# You will get/be hit by a ball - is there a difference?

Tags: word-choice, get-be

I am struggling with understanding *get* vs *be*:

> He is so slow, he will get hit by the ball.

VS

> He is so slow, he will be hit by the ball.

It is the same? I know that *get* can replace *be* or indicate change of state/condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passive with "to get"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143421/passive-with-to-get)

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the word *[get](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get)* means

> to become or cause to become or act as specified: *to get a window open, get one's hair cut, get wet*

This *becoming* sense is closely related to the simple future tense of *to be* in your examples.

> . . . he will get hit by the ball.
>
> . . . he will be hit by the ball

This even works in the past tense

> . . . he got hit with the ball.
>
> . . . he was hit with the ball.

This usage of *get* is often followed by reflexive pronouns such as *himself*, *yourself*, *myself*.

> I don't want to get myself in trouble

While your two sentences can be viewed as equivalent, some might read a slight suggestion that *get hit* implies some personal involvement or causation.

> He got in a fight.

seems to subtly suggest more culpability than

> He was in a fight.