# Passive with "to get"

Tags: passive-voice, get-passive

In spoken English (at least in America), passives are often formed with "to get" rather than "to be;" I would wager the majority of the time:

- he got hit by a car
- I get driven to work
- I've gotten called for jury duty eight times

Are there specific verbs that prefer "be" to "get," or vice-versa, or semantic differences between these forms? I cannot think of any.

Comment: “He got killed by a shot to the back of the head” doesn't work for me—has to be “he was killed” there. I cannot think of a systematic reason for this, though.

Comment: "That's How You Got Killed Before"  by Elvis Costello         http://www.metrolyrics.com/thats-how-you-got-killed-before-lyrics-elvis-costello.html     Sometimes it is used with a reflexive pronoun with the implied meaning not purely passive.  "He got himself killed, standin' there in the line-of-fire."  In my experience, 'to get' is often used in a casual register to form passive constructions.  It would sound "wrong" in formal register.

Comment: And even in a 'casual register', I (personally) would not say 'got called', but 'I've been called ...'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You will get/be hit by a ball - is there a difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121260/you-will-get-be-hit-by-a-ball-is-there-a-difference)

Comment: @niamulbengali I vote to close in the other direction: there's a better answer here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a long discussion in the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p1441-1443) of the typical contexts in which the *get-passive* is more likely than the *be-passive*. The CGEL notes that:

> i Get-passives tend to be avoided in formal style,
>
> ii Get-passives are found only with dynamic verbs,
>
> iii Get-passives are more conducive to an agentive interpretation of
> the subject,
>
> iv Get-passives are characteristically used in clauses involving
> adversity or benefit.

Following are various extracts from CGEL's discussion of points ii-iv. (The authors do not regard point i as in need of further comment.)

> **The restriction to dynamic verbs**: *be* is not replaceable by *get*
> in examples such as:
> *It got believed that the letter was a forgery.
> Obviously, the manager gets feared by most of the staff.*
>
> **Agentivity**: Take for example the pair *Jill was/got arrested*. Either
> could be used used to report an event where Jill simply had a patient
> role, but if I believe she set out to provoke the police into
> arresting her or was careless in letting it happen I will be more
> likely to use the *get* version.
>
> **Adversity and benefit**: *Get* occurs predominantly in passives
> representing situations that have an adverse or a beneficial effect on
> the subject referent, or on someone associated with it, rather than in
> passives representing purely neutral situations. Typical examples: *Kim got sacked. My watch got stolen.*
>
> Such examples are much more natural than, say, *The milk got bought at
> the store down the road* or *The door got opened by a shabbily dressed
> old man*.

---

Swan, in his pedagogic grammar, *Practical English Usage* (p223) notes a further difference:

> The *get-passive* is not often used to talk about longer, more deliberate planned actions:
>
> ?Our house got built in 1827.
>
> ?Parliament got opened on Thursday.

Finally, the *Cambridge Grammar of English* (a different text to the CGEL) observes (p539):

> Prepositional phrases expressing an agent, although they do occur
> with *get-passives*, are far rarer than with *be-passives*.

In other words, *She got arrested by the Austrian police* is less likely than *She was arrested by the Austrian police.*

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, those are all British-English guides. I think the "got" form is more widely used and accepted in American English than in British English.

Comment: @Nxx. Well, two of the three co-authors of the CGEL chapter on the passive are American. Anyway, are AE speakers more likely than BE speakers to say, for example, _This book got written in 1873_ or _The hotel will get opened in 2014_? I'm interested in any references to support the claim that they would.

Answer (score 6):

If *he was hit by a car*, that's the driver's fault; if *he got hit by a car*, that's his own fault. (By semantics, though this is mostly not intended in real use.)

If you happen to come in the way of a bad driver, you may **be** hit by his car.
If you don't give way, you may **get** hit by his car.

As already stated, most speakers may not maintain this distinction.

Comment: I think you are reading too much into the use of the word "got" here. If someone breaks into my house and steals my stuff, I can say "I got robbed" without implying that it was my own fault. I don't think "got" implies blame.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Reading less, not too much. It's only when one ignores the patent semantics that the difference blurs. Think of it. :) (*meta*: That comment may have unwittingly prompted others to down vote the answer.)

Comment: No, Kris's interpretation is correct much of the time. There's an invited inference in the _get_-passive that the patient subject is not totally devoid of responsibility. Compare _John was arrested last night_ and _John got arrested last night_. It's not obligatory, and it depends on circumstances (like all pragmatics), but it's quite common.

Comment: And there's certainly this inference in _John and Julie got married_. There's often at least a punctive vs stative aspect difference (contrast _John and Julie were married by that time_). And see Barrie's answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44691/grammar-of-married-in-getting-married/44694#44694) for previous discussion of the _get_-passive.

Comment: I admit that sometimes "got" implies who caused the action. However I think as it stands Kris's answer is incomplete. There are too many cases where "got" does not imply agency or blame.

Comment: Saying "By semantics it means this, but people use it to mean that" is incoherent. The "semantics" of a sentence are what it means, not what somebody thinks it ought to mean.

Comment: @ColinFine That's the problem. We stop at pragmatics, mostly. Rights?

Comment: "but if I believe she set out to provoke the police into arresting her or was careless in letting it happen I will be more likely to use the *get* version." (Agentivity) quoted by Shoe in his answer supports my contention.