# Is the expression "to get understood" correct?

Tags: meaning, expressions, expression-choice

Can I say

> Get yourself understood.

with the sense of "make yourself understood"?

Are both correct? Is there a difference in meaning between the two?

Comment: Hello,MS. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+yourself+understood%2Cmake+yourself+understood&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20yourself%20understood%3B%2Cc0) (yes; there are two) reinforce my initial opinion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can see that's it's not used a lot, but is it *wrong*?

Comment: Some [related reading from the CGEL](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/143448/300).

Comment: An answer on [WordReference Forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/understood.1938706/) says '[Use]
"As long as you make yourself understood" [instead]. This is better.' I agree that the get-passive here is not as good. Its use would be highly informal, and probably be regarded as slang in the UK. Especially bare get-passives with non-action verbs are usually unidiomatic (Get understood / Get considered / Get regarded / Get known).

Answer (score -2):

Actually it depends to the situation. If the situation refers the future no matter how long it is to be happened, "to get understood" is correct. If the situation refers to the past, "to get understood" is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Even if we ignore any issues with *get understood*, I disagree with the comment about *to X* being *absolutely wrong* with reference to the past. Consider, for example: "He went there yesterday to get some food." or, if we stick with the OP's *get (himself) understood*, "He posted his reasoning to *get (himself) understood*".