# Why is "His theory got disproved" bad English?

Tags: verbs

I've been told that "His theory got disproved" is not correct English (even in colloquial speech), and that I should say "His theory has been disproved" instead. I usually use "to get" as a substitute for "have been" (e.g. "He got thrown out of school" instead of "He has been thrown out of school"), but why is that not possible in the sentence mentioned in the title (or is it not possible at all, and I've been using "to get" wrong all the time)?

Comment: There are certain people who don't like the word *got* and think it's incorrect English whenever it is used.  Ignore them. Maybe *got* is more colloquial, but it's not wrong.

Comment: In formal settings, stick to a form of _be_ for passive voice.  A scientific journal will frown on things such as _The sample got heated to 350 C_.  In the other hand, if  someone disses your favorite football player, go ahead and tell them to _get stuffed_.

Comment: *His theory was (/has been) disproved.* Using *got* sounds terrible to this speaker of American English.

Comment: @Spencer  "Sample got" got 3000 hits in Google Scholar. I scrolled through over 100 pages of hits. It seems to be a real 3000 hits. About half could have been reworded with *was*. "The sample accidentally got heated to 350 C" would be acceptable to a lot more people. *Got* isn't usually used when an agent accomplishes their intent. It tends to be used for bad/surprising things.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143421/passive-with-to-get

Answer (score 0):

The use of *get* to form a passive is well established in English of all varieties. Examples can be found in the OED dating back to the 1600s.

Where some people acquire an aversion to forms of the verb "get" is beyond me.

Comment: Where we get the aversion from is not hearing it regularly in our social circles. No-one in my social circle uses "innit", and I inadvertently judge people when I hear it. The same applies to passive *get*.