# Being vs Getting in passive voice sentences

Tags: meaning, differences

Are ***being*** and ***getting*** interchangeable in passive voice sentences?
[Here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103521/getting-vs-being-in-passive-voice-sentences) we can see that the people have pretty much concluded they **are**, indeed.

However, my schoolbook suggests only ***being*** as the possible answer in the following sentence. (it is a part 2 - gap text - exercise taken from a CAE student book).

> They believe that the freedom of the individual is already in danger
>   of ***being*** seriously weakened.

Can you help me find some sources that can help me understand why getting is not working for the sentence? Or have the authors forgotten to include it as a possibility?

Comment: There's a discussion of the contexts in which the _get passive_ is more likely here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143421/passive-with-to-get

Comment: 'Becoming' would also fit in the sentence but 'getting' is an active matter.   The attempt to use 'get' or 'getting' as an active verb is non-idiomatic and also non-grammatical.